# How to list objects in library using as3 at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, list, runtime

i would like to, somehow, interact with my library.. I have a lot (near 100) of objects exported as classes at specific folder into library, and i would like to get its properties. How can i do it?
there is some AS3 method that can list exported object classes?

Comment: What do you mean "somehow interact with my library" there are many ways you could interact with a library.  Are you looking for reflection, if so check out describeType, are you looking for static code analysis, if so check out swfdump.jar, are you looking for something else, if so please be more specific.

Comment: I have answered to similar question earlier here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467631/how-do-i-list-a-potentially-large-amount-of-classes-in-a-specific-package-as/8467828#8467828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in runtime , try this :

```
trace(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames());
```

before version 11.3 use this library :

http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/

Comment: Have in mind that this method works only since Flash Player 11.3 version!