# AIR iOS getQualifiedDefinitionNames()

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, applicationdomain

When i compile the iOS version, the `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames()` function returns a vector with length 0.

OS X, Windows, and Android versions work fine, but not the iOS version.

I have tested it with fast and AOT compilation. Also, i have created a simple project with this single line with the same result. AIR versions tested are *3.9* and *4.0*.

I don't know if it is a known bug or something is wrong. What could be the cause?

Comment: Why would you need that ? maybe there are other ways to achieve that.. you are icomplete in your question... sorry

Comment: Hi! My data is JSON Format. All complex objects contain a Class field that I use to build the Object in AS3. It works in all platforms except iOS. The class field doesn't contain the full package name, only the class name.

Comment: @awakening if no luck then try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467631/how-do-i-list-a-potentially-large-amount-of-classes-in-a-specific-package-as/8467828#8467828

Comment: Thanks @RajaJaganathan . The first solution could be valid. I tested the other alternative with ByteCodeType.fromLoader function but it didn't work. It launched an error "#2030: End of File was encountered". Maybe iOS version has a problem with the loaderInfo, and it returns 0 with getQualifiedDefinitionNames function.